# How to update list of work items linked to a build pipeline via the REST API/CLI in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to add/update a list of work items (id) that are linked to a current build pipeline from some PowerShell script using the Azure Rest API, how can I do that? Thanks in advance

I can get the list by using the API, but not sure how to update it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-work-items-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0